# adding a static library to my xcode command line project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, lpsolve

I have a liblpsolve55.a file and liblpsolve55.dylib file which I got from a directory at macports. I didn't install anything using macports but I used this [link](http://mirror.pnl.gov/macports/packages/lp_solve/) to get the liblpsolve55.a and liblpsolve55.dylib files.

Now as I understand I have to link these files to my project. I am creating a simple command line project to understand various functions in the library.

Now how can I link link this .a file or .dylib file to my project. Can I just put the .a file in my project directory and use a command like #import to link it with my main file? Is there a tutorial which shows how to use an external .a/.dylib file(which you did not compile) in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved the issue at hand. I just added my static library to the project directory and included the necessary header files. now the code is working.